# How can I pass 2 variables from one form to another?

Tags: c#, forms

I have 2 forms: Game and newPlayer. When you press a button in Game, it opens the dialog of the newPlayer form, where someone would type his/her name and choose a Color in a comboBox between red, green, blue or yellow. I save that information in 2 variables: name (string) and color (int - being the index of the comboBox). I want to pass those 2 variables to the form Game.

I've tried unifying them in just one string and pass just one variabe to Game form, without success.

```
public partial class Game : Form
{

    static int nPlayers = 4;
    static List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    public string name = "";

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (newPlayer np = new newPlayer())
        {
            if (np.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.name = np.TheValue;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + name + "!");

    }
```

and then:

```
public partial class newPlayer : Form
{
    public string name = "";

public string TheValue
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                this.name = textBox1.Text + comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(newPlayer.name);
                this.Close();
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Write your name and choose a color!");
            }
        } else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write your name and choose a color!");
        }
    }
```

On the MessageBox of newPlayer it appears correctly like "Name1", for example. But on the MessageBox of Game, it appears empty. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Please do not use `static` variables. They will cause you pain.

Comment: I've changed them for public variables now and I am refering to them as this.name instead of newPlayer.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to set the `DialogResult` when closing the form.

Try this:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

---

If I were writing this code I might have done it more like this:

**Game:**

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _playerName = "";

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (NewPlayer np = new NewPlayer())
        {
            if (np.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _playerName = np.PlayerName;
                MessageBox.Show($"Welcome {_playerName}!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NewPlayer:**

```
public partial class NewPlayer : Form
{
    public NewPlayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _playerName = "";

    public string PlayerName
    {
        get { return _playerName; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "" && comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            _playerName = $"{textBox1.Text}{comboBox1.SelectedIndex}";
            MessageBox.Show(_playerName);
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write your name and choose a color!");
        }
    }
}
```